# CanJS: Is there a way to assign the whole viewModel of a component on instantiation?

Tags: canjs

I'm making a list-like component in my application and I would like to extract the list item into a separate child component. I've struggled for a while but found no way to assign viewModel of a component on instantiation.

Stripped example:

```
can.Component.extend({
    template: '{{#items}}' +
              // '<item data="{.}"></item>' + // (1) Can do this.
              // '<item title="title" value="value"></item>' + // (2) Can do this
              '<item @viewModel="{.}"></item>' + // Want something like this.
              '{{/items}}'
    // ...
});

can.Component.extend({
    tag: 'item'
    // ...
});
```

Working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scaryzet/7pnh5ujn/1/

Currently I know of 3 ways to cope with this.

1. Bind child component's data to a key (like in my fiddle by the link above).
2. Bind all needed fields by specifying them all in the tag - pain in ass.
3. Don't extract individual list items to separate components.

I hope there is a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am just starting out with CanJS but perhaps the following could work.

There appears to be a `data` [helper](http://canjs.com/docs/can.mustache.helpers.data.html) that you can use to pass the context.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697459/how-do-i-pass-a-can-compute-into-a-can-component) where it seems to solve this issue.  I do not know whether this is the preferred mechanism but it does seem to work.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/t61m4h2n/).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution to my problem here: https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/1978

Actually you can define custom behavior for initializing viewModel by providing a viewModel function. This is also covered in docs: http://canjs.com/docs/can.Component.prototype.viewModel.html

As suggested in the answer on the github issue, the following approach might be used to use the view context at the point of component instantiation as the viewModel of the component instance without specifying explicit bindings in component's tag.

```
can.Component.extend({
  tag: "item",
  viewModel: function (attrs, parentScope) {
    return parentScope._context;
  }
})
```